# Lock down a folder

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, folder

I only want to give permissions to a few people or a small group of people - this is only for one folder. Can I do this? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 3):

You need to “Stop Inheriting Permissions” on that specific folder and then add peoples or groups to the same folder.

1. Go into the specific list
2. "List"-tab (in ribbon) -> Shared width
3. In the "shared with" modal box -> Advanced
4. Stop Inheriting Persmissions (ribbon)
5. Then add person / group to the library

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-set-unique-permissions-for-folders-and-documents/

Comment: Can you please add the main steps for doing this to your post? It will make the post remain helpful even if the link breaks :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1.In the document library, hover the mouse over the folder to see the drop down menu.
>
> 2.Activate the drop down menu by pressing the down arrow
>
> 3.Choose Manage Permissions
>
> 4.Click the Actions menu and choose Edit permissions. Confirm that you want to break inheritance of permissions from the parent.
>
> 5.Edit the permissions as required.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610849/document-library-sub-folder-target-audience